# Android OPENGL2 not drawing texture to quad

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to get some textures rendered on quads, but the screen turns out empty.
(Open GL 2.0)
I formerly used a static color shader on the quads, and the quads did appear on screen, so the positioning is fine.

UPDATE: Now I can see black textures only...

Here is my code:

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 uTMatrix; 
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vTex;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;
varying vec2 TexCoord0;
void main(){
    TexCoord0 = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * uTMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Frag Shader:

```
varying highp vec2 TexCoord0;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorMap, TexCoord0);
}
```

onDrawFrame():

```
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        final float halfw = mWidth / 2f;
        final int rowHeight = mRowHeight;
        final float r = (float) rowHeight / halfw;

        int i = mFirstRow;

        final float initial = (float) ((i * rowHeight) - mScroll) / halfw;

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mTMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mTMatrix, 0, 0, -initial, 0);

        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, 0, mVertBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, 0, mTexBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTexHandle);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        final int l = mLastRow;
        for (; i <= l; i++) {
            if (\*A check to see if the bitmap is cached*\) {
                GLES20.glUniform1i(muTextureHandle, i);
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muTMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                        mTMatrix, 0);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            }

            Matrix.translateM(mTMatrix, 0, 0, -r, 0);
        }

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTexHandle);
```

loadTexture:

```
        public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context c) {
            int[] texture = new int[1];
            texture[0] = mRow;
            GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, texture, 0);
            texture[0] = mRow;
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

            // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            // Different possible texture parameters, e.g.
            // GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

            Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap;
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = mEmptyBitmap;
            }
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        }
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing to see you're calling GLES20.glDeleteTextures(..) just before you bind it for loading texture into it.

Comment: There is a seperate thread that loads images and draws them into the bitmap, so the texture will have to change a few times. the deleteTextures call is meant to clear the old invalid texture and replace it with an updated one. (Although it may not do what I think it does... I'm very new to OpenGL)

Comment: I think it's not necessary. Once you've received ids/names (I don't know exact term for them) for textures from glGenTextures, you can 'reuse' them from then on, and simply use bind plus GLUUtils.texImage2D to update their contents.

Comment: OK, removed the line, problem remains though...

Comment: ``gl_TexCoord[0].st`` looks rather suspicious in your fragment shader too, and I'm a bit surprised if you haven't faced compile errors as there's no such built-in variable in GLSL ES 1.0. I can't tell for sure if this helps with your problem though but changing it to ``TexCoord0`` shouldn't do any harm either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, now there is a change - I see only black textures.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally there's this one line I'm not sure what it's supposed to do;

```
if (\*A check to see if the bitmap is cached*\) {
    GLES20.glUniform1i(muTextureHandle, i); // ??
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing your goal is to update GL_TEXTURE0 constantly though, in which case you should put constant value `0` into `muTextureHandle`. Or remove this line all together as zero is the default.

Comment: I tried replacing muTextureHandle with 0, didn't solve the problem. If I were to remove the line altogether, how will GL_TEXTURE0 be updated?